# Define a constant instead of duplicating this literal 3 times sonar

Tags: javascript, react-native, sonarqube

I am wondering how I would refactor the following. Basically, after I get the user information from google, it is validated since a specific domain might be allowed. If it passes that one, we validate the token against a back end api.

Sonar is complaining on the use of **return displayAlert('LoginFailed')** three times. Given the methods have unique use, I am wondering what could be done to improve it?

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {View, Alert} from 'react-native';
import {LocalizationContext} from 'library/localization';
import ServiceAuth from 'services/ServiceAuth';
import {saveLoggedInDetails} from 'library/userInformation';

const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const {translations} = useContext(LocalizationContext);

  const displayAlert = (msg) =>{
      //translations happen here
    Alert.alert("Failed", msg)
    return false;
  }


  const validateToken = async (userGoogleInfo) => {
    const {idToken} = userGoogleInfo;
    let serviceAuth = ServiceAuth.getInstance();
    try {
      return await serviceAuth.validateT(idToken);
    } catch (error) {
      //show alert here
      return displayAlert('LoginFailed')
    }
  };


  const authorize = async (userGoogleInfo) => {
    const allowedDomains = [];
    let reply = {ok: false};
    //check if domain is allowed etc and set to true.
    if (!reply['ok']) {
      return displayAlert('InvalidDomain');
    }

    try {
      const userInfo = await validateToken(userGoogleInfo);

      if (userInfo) {
       console.log("okay")
      } else {
        return displayAlert('LoginFailed')
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return displayAlert('LoginFailed')
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
        <View>
          <Text>Hello</Text>
        </View>
    </>
  );
};
export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The message is a little bit confusing but sonar is complaining only about the `LoginFailed` string used three times as parameter.

Create a constant as, for example:

```
const LOGIN_FAILED = 'LoginFailed';
```

And then use it in all the three calls to displayAlert:

```
return displayAlert(LOGIN_FAILED);
```

Comment: thanks! that worked. I totally overlooked it. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I have these millions of times in my app. Is that a quick way or some extension that does the job for me? Just curious!